# md5 hash with operator + inside

Tags: php

For an api, I need to get `md5(md5(text)+timeUNIX)` so I made this in php :

```
md5((md5(123456789)+1498740101);
```

But it returns `ceac5623c9b370f9581d4f61764c5b6d` and I know that this hash with this time and this text is `dbbc59e0b318fb9a4e64fc175644bf92`.

Does someone know? is there any issues/problems with the operator + in md5's function ?

Comment: There're __no__ issues with `+` operator. `+` operator __sums__ values, not __concatenates__.

Comment: thanks, in the api specs there is just `md5(md5(text)+timeUNIX)`  but what the api needs exactly is to concatenate so I just replace `+` by `.` and it's works

Comment: Which "api specs" do you refer to?

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer to your question 
md5((md5(123456789).(1498740101)));
in your example you calculate not concantinate.